# Start an android thread when a button pressed

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 3 buttons to turn on a different led, using wifi. What am I trying to do is to start a thread when a button is pressed. The thread will do a networking stuff which is to send a String of instruction code. But when I pressed the button, it stops running. And I want to display the exception in the toast if there is an exception occured. Please help.
Here is the code:

This is the activity that will display 3 buttons.

```
package com.gfhz.appliancecontrol;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LightsMenuActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights_menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_lights_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void checkLightsStatus() {
        /*instructionID = "0400";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionSocket.class);
        intent.putExtra(INSTRUCTION, instructionID);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }

    public void powerLamp1 (View view) {
        ConnectionSocket cs = new ConnectionSocket();
        cs.sendInstruction("0401");
    }
    public void powerLamp2(View view) {
        ConnectionSocket cs = new ConnectionSocket();
        cs.sendInstruction("0402");
    }
    public void powerLamp3(View view){
        ConnectionSocket cs = new ConnectionSocket();
        cs.sendInstruction("0403");
    }
}
```

And this is the activity that will execute the thread.

```
package com.gfhz.appliancecontrol;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectionSocket extends Activity{

Socket client;
ConnectionInfoActivity conInfo;
String instructionCode;
String serverAddr;
OutputStream os;
DataOutputStream dos;
String stoast;

public void sendInstruction (String instruction) {

    // Get the DEVICE ID
    String devId = conInfo.getDevId();
    // Concatenate instruction message and device Id
    instructionCode = devId.concat(instruction);

    // Get the SERVER IP ADDRESS
    serverAddr = "192.168.1.105";

    // Initialize PORT
    final int port = 2000;

    new Thread (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try{
                // Open a socket
                client = new Socket(serverAddr, port);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(instructionCode);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                stoast = "Unknown Host Exception" + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated cach block
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Display in TOAST
                stoast = "IO Exception" + e.toString();
            } finally {
                if (client != null) {
                    try {
                        client.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stoast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: The ConnectionSocket class can not extend Activity. Move the Toast in the finally block to see the error. Also for ConnectionSocket class you need a constructor to initialize all the objects that you use in the sendInstruction method.

Comment: @goran Thanks, Goran. But I still confused about the constructor, what are the objects that have to be initialized in the constructor of ConnectionSocket class? Can you make the code of ConnectionSocket class based on my code? :)